# movieClip not stopping always looping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-builder

I have a class that gets a movieClip  and then using addChild adds it to be displayed. Problem is that I cannot play or stop it at all. Basically I can't interact with the movieClip.

Here is the code:

```
public function Avatar(movieClip:DisplayObject) //class constructor
{   ...
    avatarSprite = MovieClip(movieClip)
    addChild(avatarSprite);
    avatarSprite.gotoAndStop(1); //this is not working
    trace(avatarSprite.currentFrame) //always returns 1
    trace(avatarSprite.isPlaying) // returns false
    ...
    }
```

When I run the code the movieClip plays in a loop and doesn't stop  as I expect it to. I am not sure what's the problem. As you can see I didn't do anything too complicated. Any idea what I am missing here please?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** As miguelSantirso pointed out. The problem is with the nested animations in the movieClip and not the actual code itself. Does anyone know how to stop nested animations from playing?

Comment: Isn't there a play() function on the timeline?

Comment: I don't think it should matter, but I tried adding avatarSprite.play() as u suggested. No improvements though. 

This is what you are meant right?

Comment: Sorry, I mean; is there code on the timeline, inside that avatarSprite movieclip? You should go to the Flash IDE and check that out.

Comment: does `avatarSprite.stop()` not work? If not, add `stop(); to the first frame (or maybe another specific frame) in the action panel of your .fla (press F9 to open the panel).

Comment: Might need to see more code. The issue does not seem to be with the code you posted.  How do you instantiate the avatarSpriteClass? how are you calling the Avatar() function?

Comment: The problem turned out to be from the nested animations and not the code. I will edit the original post. Thanks for the tips, keep them coming =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will stop all nested movieClips (or play them if you pass false to the useStop parameter)

```
function recursiveStop(parentClip:DisplayObjectContainer, useStop:Boolean = true, gotoFrame:Object = null):void {
    var tmpClip:MovieClip = parentClip as MovieClip;
    if (tmpClip) {
        if (useStop) {
            (gotoFrame != null) ? tmpClip.gotoAndStop(gotoFrame) : tmpClip.stop();
        }else {
            (gotoFrame != null) ? tmpClip.gotoAndPlay(gotoFrame) : tmpClip.play();
        }
    }

    var i:int = parentClip.numChildren;
    while(i--){
        if(parentClip.getChildAt(i) is DisplayObjectContainer){
            recursiveStop(parentClip.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer, useStop, gotoFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There was a little problem with the first line of the method. It should be (useStop) ? parentClip.stop() : parentClip.play(); Otherwise the parentClip will always stop regardless if useStop is false.

But other than that it works flawlessly. Thanks for the help and thank u all for the tips =)

Answer (score 1):

Check that there are not nested animations inside your movieclip. Pausing a MovieClip does not stop the internal animations.

Comment: you are right...there are nested animations inside the movieClip. I made a dummy movieClip without any nested animations and it worked fine.

Do you know of anyway to stop nested animations from playing? Since I got the art from an external source it is hard for me to change it.

Comment: The only way I know is iterating through the movieclips recursively. If you look it up in Google you may find something.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of casting it to a movieclip, try handling it AS a movieclip.

```
avatarSprite = movieClip as MovieClip;
```

(considering the incoming movieclip IS actually a movieclip ofcourse...)